# Why no one seems to use FreeBSD to host Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, freebsd

We use FreeBSD 8.2, Rails 3.0.7, postgresql 8.3, passenger and nginx for our production servers.
http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/cvsweb.cgi/ports/www/rubygem-passenger/

We seems to have a odd configuration because no one seems to have something like ours. I feel a little alone. :)

Nevertheless, this configuration is quite easy to setup, it performs well and it's very stable.

Is there a particular reason why Rails deveopper seems to avoid FreeBSD as a production server ?

Comment: Better asked on serverfault and flagged as such.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I read somewhere that 37signals uses FreeBSD but I can't find the reference right now, sorry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably most of development is made on Linux boxes, so it's natural to choose the same or very similar environment for production.

Comment: I would be very interested in an answer to the question 'Why have you chosen FreeBSD for server.

Comment: Same type of thoughts. I am on mac osx and *bsd plateform is more max osx like than linux box. Personal taste also.

Comment: And it seems to have more rails dev. on osx than on Linux. So, it's quite odd.

Comment: It looks like in that old tale, where three blind ones were talking how does an elephant looks like. I am on Linux, so I think most of people work on Linux. ;-)  Maybe hosting with Linux servers is easier to find? In fact, when we have no real numbers, we cannot be sure whether "Rails deveopper seems to avoid FreeBSD" really. Maybe it's no longer true? I have chosen Linux for my servers because: 1) I know Linux, 2) our sysadmin knows Linux.

Comment: yeah, I see what you mean. It can de interesting to get real number whereas based on subjective opinions.